# doesn't open the web browser when run the project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I try to run my project. There is no error and it compiles successfully, but it doesn't open the web browser.

Previously when I ran my project, it opened the web browser, but now it doesn't open the web browser. What is wrong?

Comment: What is a web bower?!

Comment: thanks. It working After restaring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Testing Web Pages in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/df5x06h3.aspx) has a good deal of information on how to properly debug your application in a browser using Visual Studio.

> By default, Visual Studio uses your default browser to test pages. To use a different browser or Page Inspector, right-click the page in Solution Explorer and then click either Browse With or View in Page Inspector. The Browse With lets you select a browser from a list, add new browsers to the list, or set one as the default browser. (The default browser setting here applies only to the Visual Studio environment and not to Windows.)
>
> To specify a start page, right-click the page in Solution Explorer and then click Set As Start Page.

Comment: I did. This not help. So I have to change any IIS setting..?

Answer (score 0):

In the solution explorer, right-click on the root project node, and select "Set as Start-up Project".  When you launch a debug session, it should now open your operating system's default web browser pointing to the page you have setup in the web tab of your project properties.

Comment: I did. This not help. So I have to change any IIS setting..?

Answer (score 0):

in my case, just removed specified ip of kestrel handler like this:

```
app.Run("http://0.0.0.0:7125")
```

to

```
app.Run()
```